# Error while I use math.atan in Python!

Tags: python

When I do `1/2` in Python why does it give me zero? Even if I coerce it with `float(1/2)` still I get zero. Why? And how can I get around it?

When I give `arctan(1/2)` I get 0 as answer, but when I give `arctan(.5)` I get the correct answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Python 2.x uses integer division for integers, so:

```
1/2 == 0
```

evaluates to True.

You want to do:

```
1.0/2
```

or do a

```
from __future__ import division
```

Answer (score 6):

First,  `1/2` is integer division.  Until Python 3.0.

```
>>> 1/2
0
>>> 1.0/2.0
0.5
>>>
```

Second, use `math.atan2` for this kind of thing.

```
>>> math.atan2(1,2)
0.46364760900080609
>>> math.atan(.5)
0.46364760900080609
```

Answer (score 3):

```
atan(float(1)/2)
```

If you do:

```
atan(float(1/2))
```

in Python 2.x, but without:

```
from __future__ import division
```

the 1/2 is evaluated first as 0, then 0 is converted to a float, then atan(0.0) is called. This changes in Python 3, which uses float division by default even for integers.  The short portable solution is what I first gave.

Comment: Python 3 changes this? That's going to mess with my mind. I'm used to doing everything with integers, in C, since I'm an embedded software engineer.

Comment: Yes.  See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/ .  You can still use // to truncate.

Answer (score 2):

```
float(1)/float(2)
```

If you divide int / int you get an int, so float(0) still gives you 0.0

Answer (score 2):

From the standard:

The / (division) and // (floor division) operators yield the quotient of their arguments. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. Plain or long integer division yields an integer of the same type; the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result.

Answer (score 1):

As these answers are implying, 1/2 doesn't return what you are expecting.  It returns zero, because 1 and 2 are integers (integer division causes numbers to round down).  Python 3 changes this behavior, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Your coercing doesn't stand a chance because the answer is already zero before you hand it to float.

Try 1./2

Answer (score 1):

In Python, dividing integers yields an integer -- 0 in this case.

There are two possible solutions. One is to force them into floats: 1/2. (note the trailing dot) or float(1)/2.

Another is to use "from **future** import division" at the top of your code, and use the behavior you need.

python -c 'from **future** import division;import math;print math.atan(1/2)' yields the correct 0.463647609001

Answer (score 1):

If 1/2 == 0 then float(1/2) will be 0.0. If you coerce it to float after it's been truncated it'll still be truncated.

There are a few options:

- Add the following import: `from __future__ import division`. This will make the / operator divide "correctly" in that module. You can use // if you need truncating division.
- Coerce either of the operands to a float. eg: `float(1)/2`
- If you're actually using constants then just add a decimal point instead of using float(), eg: `1.0/2` or `1/2.0` or `1.0/2.0`